# trouble writing fractions in mathML

Tags: google-chrome, mathml

I am trying to write the fraction 2/3 in MathML with the 2 over the 3.

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mfrac>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mn>3</mn>
  </mfrac>
</math>
```

Unfortunately this only comes out as "2 3" where did I go wrong?

---

Nobody writes MathML by hand but this is what the computer generates.  And I noticed it doesn't work, even in jsFiddle

```html
<math>  
  <mfrac bevelled="true">
     <mfrac>
        <mi> a </mi>
        <mi> b </mi>
     </mfrac>
     <mfrac>
        <mi> c </mi>
        <mi> d </mi>
     </mfrac>
  </mfrac>
</math>
```

Comment: What browser are you using to render it? Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/mfrac to check out the browser compatibility (basically, it works on Firefox and Safari). Do you already know [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have this question tagged "Google Chrome", which doesn't support MathML. See [Missing MathML implementation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6606).

The other Bob who answered mentioned MathJax. This is (in my opinion) an acceptable temporary solution for Chrome users. The only acceptable permanent solution is MathML's inclusion in Chrome. Without it, Chrome cannot claim to be standards-compliant.